# STL containers, allocator, and pointer wrapper

Tags: pointers, stl, containers, allocator, libc++

I've made a customized slab allocator which uses mmap to allocate fixed-size segment pool. These segments are logically continuous but physically discrete.
I also defined a pointer wrapper class, which contains an offset from logical start point of the pool.
The pointer class looks like:

```
template<typename T>
struct offptr_t {
    typedef offptr_t<T> this_t;
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef OFFSET difference_type;
    template<typename U> struct rebind { typedef offptr_t<U> other; };
    offptr_t(const mem_pool *p, OFFSET o)
    : pool(p), offset(o)
    {}
    // ...
};
```

Here is the allocator:

```
template<typename T>
struct mem_pool_allocator {
public:
    typedef mem_pool_allocator<T> this_t;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef offptr_t<T> pointer;
    typedef const offptr_t<T> const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef int64_t difference_type;
    template< class U > struct rebind { typedef mem_pool_allocator<U> other; };
    // ...
};
```

Then I defined pointer_traits and iterator_traits classes as STL required:

```
namespace std {
    template<typename T>
    struct pointer_traits<offptr_t<T>> {
        typedef typename offptr_t<T> pointer;
        template<typename U> struct rebind { typedef offptr_t<U> other; };
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct iterator_traits<offptr_t<T>> {
        typedef typename offptr_t<T> pointer;
        typedef typename pointer::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename pointer::element_type value_type;
        typedef typename pointer::element_type &reference;
        typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    };
}   // End of namespace std
```

When I use these class with STL containers in libc++, several compilation errors occurred in c++/v1/vector:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline
void
__vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>::__destruct_at_end(const_pointer __new_last, false_type) _NOEXCEPT
{
    while (__new_last != __end_)
        __alloc_traits::destroy(__alloc(), const_cast<pointer>(--__end_));
}


template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY inline
void
__vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>::__destruct_at_end(const_pointer __new_last, true_type) _NOEXCEPT
{
    __end_ = const_cast<pointer>(__new_last);
}
```

Vector is using const_cast<> on the pointer type, const_cast<> can only be used with raw pointers/references and cannot be overloaded, which means it's impossible to work with customized pointer-like object.

Am I doing anything wrong or it's just a flaw of STL implementation in libc++?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bug in libc++ to me.  I'm working on a fix...

Comment: Another question is about to make custom allocator work with STL containers even the const_cast problems are solved.

My allocator uses pointer-like objects instead of raw pointers to represent a location in memory, but vectors and strings are using SBO/SSO, which need the "pointer" type returned by allocator can also represent raw pointers point to their internal buffer, i.e. a piece of code converts a reference of an element to "pointer" type regardless the element is in the internal buffer or not.

I still have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: We'll take it a step at a time.  Please feel free to google my name (which will lead to a working email) and contact me offline.